# Other forums for longer drupal questions

Tags: discussion

I have a very specific problem with a view that I don't really know how to solve. I asked a similar question about a month ago but the moderators comment that my question was a little bit long.

So I'm wondering if any of you know another forum where I can post more longer questions about content-type design or more specific questions on how to achieve certain results in a view.

Comment: I re-phrased my post from database design to content-type design (if that make sense?).
I think my question might be one of those that ask more or less for a personal opinion since it comes down to a question about how to solve the specific problem that I have. The issue is that I don't really know how I should solve the problem at all, so it's hard to partition it....

Comment: Since you are asking for _another forum_, please note that Stack Exchange sites are not forums: They are Q&A sites. If you start writing comments as answers because you think they are forums, you will find your _answers_ deleted. An answer is just for answering the question. In the same way, a question is not for asking opinions or ideas (except on the meta sites like this one).

Answer (score 3):

Questions are not usually rejected for being "too long".
Often long questions are rejected because they cover too broad a topic to be answered in a short response such as this site offers.
It can also be because they are opinion based questions like "What is the best way to do X?", which don't have a correct answer but instead have lots of different personal opinions.

Questions about content type design are often too broad and/or opinion based, which is why they are often considered off topic.

If you can single out a more specific aspect of your content type creation it may be more easy to answer.

For a question about database design you would also have to have a good reason why it is a Drupal question and not a question for the DBA stack exchange site.

A question like "How can I make a view do ...? are perfectly acceptable, however generally you will be better off if you have a view that is mostly working and you ask a question regarding a specific part of it that isn't working, not just a "Can you make me a view that meets my requirements?" type questions, which is just like trying to get someone else to do your work, in which case you're better off paying someone else to do your work.

You can try the [forums on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/forum) but you will find you will get similar results there with the same sorts of questions (unless you're in the paid services section with cash to spend).

For more information see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: This is correct: Questions are not closed basing on their length, but basing on the fact they are answerable and they can produce useful answers for which users can vote basing on their correctness, and not other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Try  IRC #drupal-support, they can 'hear you out' so to speak, and try to drive your question that way. It was helpful to me earlier. And it's very instructive to see other topics and such